# Survival Gamma Function

Tags: probability, gamma-distribution

I answered a question in my probability test but I think it's wrong!

Could you tell me with my solution is right? The question is:

Find
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{2n}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n(n-1)!}t^{n-1}e^{-t/2}dt$$

My solution:

This is the limit of survival function of a random variable $X\sim \Gamma(n,1/2)$ or a $X\sim \chi_{(2n)}^2$. That's it $S_x(2n)$.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}S_x(2n)=0$$

It this correct?

Comment: The definition seems to imply that $n$ is an integer, then taking the limit to  $0$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: In other words, given enough time the proportion surviving goes down to zero. $S_x(\infty)=0$

Comment: @YvesDaoust sorry for my lack of attention. The limit goes to $\infty$

Comment: Your solution should be fine (I didn't review the PDF), as long as they don't expect you to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty}S_x(2n) = 0$ using fancy inequalities.

Comment: @Clarinetist But Survival Function of a random variable tends to 0 when it's limit goes to $\infty$?

Comment: @Cauchy_96 Well, yes. Suppose $F$ is the CDF of a random variable. Then you know as it tends to $\infty$, it goes to $1$. The survival function $S = 1 - F$, which would tend to $0$.

Comment: @Clarinetist Other way I try to solve this question is assuming that the gamma survival function is the same as poisson cumulative distribution function. But I can't proof that equality :(